# group by with resample has column is being duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-resample

**Background**: I have covid data that I aggregated to the state level.  Then I aggregated my days to the week level (this works). However, when I run the day to week logic with almost exactly the same data just at the county level I get an error. More specifically, I'm getting the same column in the index and in the data.

The left is the rolled-up state data and right rolled up county data...
[image]

Here is the state data code that is working...

```
df_covid_data = df_covid_data.groupby("State").resample('W-SAT', label='right', closed = 'right', on='date').sum().sort_values(by=['State','date'])
```

And here is the county code (basically identical) that is not working (note if I uncomment the end I get an error, because countyFIPS is included twice). I tried removing the nan columns and this did not help...

```
df_covid_data_c = df_covid_data_c.groupby("countyFIPS").resample('W-SAT', label='right', closed = 'right', on='date').sum()#.sort_values(by=['countyFIPS','date'])
```

Here are the outputs...
[image]

PS to bring in the raw data...

```
COVID_FILE =   
    'covid_confirmed_usafacts' #https://usafacts.org/visualizations/coronavirus-covid-19-spread-map grab confirmed cases

df_cum_covid_data=pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH+COVID_FILE+'.csv', sep=',').dropna(axis=1, how='all').dropna(axis=0, how='all')#read in covid data
```

Comment: It's hard to impossible to help you with the data given in screenshots. Have a look at how you can provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/463796

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was that the county id (countyFISP) was coming in as a float and this was messing up the group by function.  If I cast it as in integer on the way in then the code ran.